# Unable to revert warning severity changes in my Unity project in Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: c#, ide, visual-studio-mac

Out of curiosity I set a Warning in VS (Deprecated) to Silent severity using the Quick Actions, (I wanted to set it to silent in one script only) however, I am unable to revert it back to a Warning. I am using Visual Studio for Mac 17.6.9. I can't find any solution for this online. I have no idea where the issue severity settings are stored.

From what I found online, I tried looking for an .editorconfig file, and went through every single preference and menu, and couldn't find anything to revert the warning severity. Specifically, I am using Unity 2023.2.12, and the NavMeshLocation should be deprecated, and it is when I mouse over it, but there is no squiggly line underneath, and it doesn't throw any warnings in the IDE when I have it compile.

I've moved the project to another computer, so I know it's project-specific. I also tried deleting the Library folder, yet this still persists.